# Entity Framework Custom SQL Query returning generic type

Tags: sql, entity-framework, xtragrid

I'm trying to make a generic reporting system so that I can add reports to my program on the fly, rather than issuing a new version of the program every time I have to add in a report.
Currently, I have it partly working;
My custom report SQL is stored in a table, along with the report name. The report name is used for the buttons for the user to click, when they click the button, I want the SQL to execute and be bound to a gridview, so it's as generic as possible.

This seems to be where the troubles come though. Getting the SQL and executing it is fine, but binding it to a gridview seems impossible, I only get one column, called Column, that displays 1 row with a value of System.Object.

I think the problem is because I'm returning data from multiple tables, i.e.

```
SELECT c.CertificateName, e.EntityName, 
       ce.CertificateDate, ce.CertificateExpiry, ce.CertificateNumber 
FROM FCERTSTest.dbo.CertificateEntries ce 
INNER JOIN FCERTSTest.dbo.Certificates c 
ON c.CertificateID = ce.Certificate_ID 
INNER JOIN FCERTSTest.dbo.Entities e 
ON e.EntityID = ce.Entity_ID 
WHERE FirstNotificationSent = '1'
```

I'm currently using

```
using (DBContainer db = new DBContainer())
{
    grid.DataSource = db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(SQLCommand).ToList();
}
```

I've tried replacing `dynamic` with `object` and get the same problem...
I understand that the best solution would be to have a custom class and replace `dynamic` with that custom class, but then I lose the benefits of it being generic as a different report may not return the same results and I would need a new custom class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`. EF doesn't work with "dynamic queries" where you don't have special type for result set.

Comment: Ahh, thankyou. I thought that might be the case. I did end up using a `SqlDataAdapter` as a temporary fix. I'll have to make it more permanent now. Is there somewhere in the EF docs that explains/covers the lack of support for dynamic queries?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) talks only about types with properties that match columns in the result set.