# Entity Framework Return Custom table in Query

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, dataservice

I needed to have a sort of View with parameters to be called by Entity Framework. After some search I came up with this solution in Oracle side:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
type PLANNING_TV is object (cod_planificacion number, des_planificacion varchar2(70), cod_cliente number, cod_compania number); 

CREATE OR REPLACE
type PLANNING_TV_TBL is table of PLANNING_TV; 

CREATE FUNCTION q_apptdept (cliente number, utilizador number)
      RETURN PLANNING_TV_TBL
   IS
      CURSOR cur (c_cliente number, c_utilizador number)
      IS
         SELECT PTV.COD_PLANIFICACION, 
           PTV.DES_PLANIFICACION, 
           PTV.COD_CLIENTE, 
           PTV.COD_COMPANIA 
          FROM RO.PLANIFICACION_TV PTV 
         WHERE PTV.COD_PAIS = 620 
           AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM F_INICIO) >= 2016 - 1 
           AND PTV.COD_COMPANIA IN (SELECT NVL(XR.COD_COMPANHIA, XR.COD_COMPANHIA) 
                                      FROM XR_VW_CLI_GRUPO_COMP_UTIL_MMS XR 
                                     WHERE XR.COD_UTILIZADOR = c_utilizador) 
           AND COD_CLIENTE = c_cliente 
         ORDER BY COD_PLANIFICACION DESC;

      ty             PLANNING_TV;
      tbl            PLANNING_TV_TBL := PLANNING_TV_TBL ();
   BEGIN
      FOR rec IN cur (cliente, utilizador) LOOP
         ty := PLANNING_TV (rec.COD_PLANIFICACION, rec.DES_PLANIFICACION, rec.COD_CLIENTE, rec.COD_COMPANIA);
         tbl.EXTEND;
         tbl (tbl.LAST) := ty;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN tbl;
   END;
```

Basically I create the data type, then the table for this data type and return a table with my data.

For getting this info I can do (oracle side):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(q_apptdept(<parm1>, <parm2>));
```

But then how can call it on my Entity Framework Data Service?

I thought something like Createquery, but I've to say the type of the return, but is a custom one. So I don't know how to put it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Custom SQL Query returning generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743290/entity-framework-custom-sql-query-returning-generic-type)

Comment: I'm using Oracle (with Entity Framework), not SQL

Comment: the post is still covering the same question the only difference is that you would be using a 'OracleDataAdapter' instead of a 'SqlDataAdapter'